# How to modify highcharts legend item click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to modify click event on highcharts legend items. Highcharts demo  http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic . I want for example: first action will be some alert and second action will be action by default(clean Tokyo line from chart). Thanks. Sorry if question not clean.

Comment: highcharts have a great documentation with jsfiddle examples, i'm sure that u you are looking for is there:  http://www.highcharts.com/ref/

Comment: updated link as above is no longer functional. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.events.legendItemClick

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You have to use the `legendItemClick`  callback like the following code

```
plotOptions: {
        line: {

           events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {
                   alert('I am an alert');
                   //return false; 
                   // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                    }
                }
            ,
            showInLegend: true
        }
    }
```

Here is [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/LDMAQ/) which shows alert when you click on legends like on Tokyo and then hide Tokyo line.

See also the [plotOptions documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.events.legendItemClick) for the event in question. Where you need to place this may differ depending on what chart type you are using.

Comment: Yes, this it!! Thank you for the accurate answer:)

Comment: To disable legend actions: `legendItemClick: function (e) {e.preventDefault()}`

Comment: anybody know how to change the cursor to default over the legend after you disable the click?

Comment: found it: legend:itemStyle:{}

Comment: Seem, that API has changed, if this example doesnt work for you, see Tony's answer below.

Answer (score 12):

For me, the legendItemClick event had to be for the series, not the line. E.g.:

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function(event) {
                    var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                    if (!confirm('The series is currently '+ 
                                 visibility +'. Do you want to change that?')) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Example from Highcharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-events-legenditemclick/