# Isolate a single series on Highcharts line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is there a way that I can change the default behaviour of the Legend click handler in Highcharts.js so that when I click on a legend label it isolates the series, instead of hiding it.  I.e. it should hide all other series on the chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/rNkBs/

```
legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        useHTML: true,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            console.log(this);
            return this.name + ' <a class="isolate-series">[isolate]</a>';
        }
    },
```

Comment: Take a look at these threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604952/how-to-modify-highcharts-legend-item-click-event

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880748/hiding-a-highcharts-series-without-using-the-legend

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nS432/2/)

Based on the API you have to add a click handler using `legendItemClick` to apply to the series.

```
     plotOptions: {
            series:{
                   events: {
                        legendItemClick: function(event) {
                            if (!this.visible)
                                return true;

                            var seriesIndex = this.index;
                            var series = this.chart.series;

                            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
                            {
                                if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
                                {

                                    series[i].visible ? series[i].hide() : series[i].show();
                                } 
                            }

                            return false;
                        }
                   }
             }
        }
```

Comment: this pretty much does what I want, but it performs very slowly with 50 series. Any idea how to improve performance?

Comment: I have no idea how to improve the performance of this, since the Y-axis is also dynamically built based on the data shown. If there was a way to cache the `series` used in that handler so that it doesn't pull all the series every time a legend is clicked, I think performance would improve.