# Why aren’t those 2 HighCharts codes equivalent? (Or is there a way to modify a call to legendItemClick after the creation of the chart object?)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does somebody know why those 2 snippets doesn’t work the same way at all?

In the first snippet I declare a function within a JSON:

```
                    plotOptions : {
                    series : {
                        events: {
                            legendItemClick: function () {
                                var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                                if (this.visible) {
                                    this.chart.container.style.height = '100px';
                                    this.chart.reflow();
                                }
                                else {
                                    this.chart.container.style.height = '400px';
                                    this.chart.reflow();
                                }
                                //this.chart.collapse();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
```

See the snippet here: [first snippet on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb9054Lv/)

N.B.: it works better on chrome if you save the files' content on your hard drive.

If you click on the legend you will see it will collapse the graph (the function is called).
In the second snippet I declare the function later on:

```
                plotOptions : {
                    series : {
                        events: {
                        }
                    }
                },
```

…

```
    myChart.options.plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick = function () {
        var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        if (this.visible) {
            this.chart.container.style.height = '100px';
            this.chart.reflow();
        }
        else {
            this.chart.container.style.height = '400px';
            this.chart.reflow();
        }
        //this.chart.collapse();
    };
```

See the snippet here:[second snippet on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3fg4obj/)

In that case if you click on the legend the function will NOT been called and the graph won’t collapse.

I guess the answer is somewhere in highcharts.js, but where?
I don’t see what to do when looking at the Highcharts.Legend API documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Legend#toc0

**Is there a way to modify a call to legendItemClick after the creation of the chart object?**

p.s.: by the way, I see exactly the same thing when looking at myChart.options.plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick in the debugger for the 2 snippets:

[image]

Comment: I do not think you can just change the config like you do, after chart init, you should probably look into the docs.

Comment: In general, changing the config is definitely possible. If you see the result of the first snippet for example, or this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604952/how-to-modify-highcharts-legend-item-click-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Notice that the second function doesn't do anything. Default functionality is triggering.
2. If you want to customize the default functionality you should consider using the [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Hi Sebastian,
Indeed originally in the second function the new code wasn't triggered as you mentioned.
Thanks to your advice to use [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) , I could overload the click of legendItem.
What I would like now is to be able to access an HighChart object to use, for example, the reflow() method.
But the following code is working:

Comment: 'document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-legend-item')[0].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if (this.classList.value.includes('highcharts-legend-item-hidden')) {
        window.alert('hello hidden');
    }
    else {
        window.alert('hello visible');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);'

Thank you.

Comment: Could you reproduce this code on the online editor and sent me a link to it?